# Angular ng-hide directive in pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In AngularJS, you could use `ng-hide` to hide an HTML element.  How would you do this using pure JS/jQuery?  If you have something like `<div id="userNotLoggedIn"></div>`, would it be `$("#userNotLoggedIn").hide()` or `$("#userNotLoggedIn").remove()`, or something else?  The goal is to not allow a site visitor to view a page if they are not logged in as a user.

Comment: `ng-hide` is probably more equivalent to [`toggle(condition)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display).

Comment: Not sure why you're bringing up angular. Is your question how to hide an HTML element? Have you read the docs for `hide` and `remove`? Are you not sure what they do?

Comment: hiding an element in this case is not the right solution, restrict navigation to that page rather using JS

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan and Rahul.

Rahul, you're saying to restrict navigation to that page.  How would you accomplish that?  Would you implement that logic on the client, or server side?

Comment: To answer aquinas, my understanding is that `hide()` is equivalent to `display: none`, which may not be what I want.  My question was simply whether `ng-if` acts similar to `.hide()`, or `.remove()`.  Since I don't really want to just hide an element, I figured `.remove()` is the best way to go.

Comment: `ng-hide` adds CSS so the element is not visible. `ng-if` decides whether or not to actually add the element to the DOM. However, like @RahulArora said, you should be restricting navigation to the page.

Comment: Thanks @BenBeck!  Excellent answer.  But, now I'm a little confused on what to do next.  If a user visits `www.mysite.com`, they'll see a generic "Welcome to My Site" message.  But, if they're logged in, they'll see a custom message, like "Welcome, {{user}}!".  Are you saying they should be routed to a different page, like `www.mysite.com/home`?  I don't really know what best practices are here (I'm new to all this).

Comment: @Farid depends on how you are building your application. If its a single page application, I would apply it on the client side only. If I am using a backend stack to render my templates, it will be on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$('#userNotLoggedIn').css('display', 'none');
```

maybe?

But if you want to be able to apply, and undo it, I recommend putting `display: none` in it's own class that can be placed and removed at will.

Something like

```
.myHideClass {
   display: none;
}

$(`#userNotLoggedIn`).addClass('myhideClass');
$(`#userNotLoggedIn`).removeClass('myhideClass');
```

Now when you do whatever logic you have to see if they're logged, when they are logged in do nothing. If they are not logged in, add `myHideClass`, once they do log in remove `myHideClass`

**Edit:**

One problem though, is I'm pretty sure `display: none;` is still going to have your elements visible in the DOM if you're in something like a debugger.

Angular has a `ng-if` attr you can drop on tags and tie to a boolean. Like `ng-if="userIsLoggedIn"` where `userIsLoggedIn` is a boolean in your controller that's set to `true` or `false`.

In the dom while `userIsLoggedIn` is true the element and everything in it, is in the dom, but; if `userIsLoggedIn === false` then in the dom if you inspect it, your div is not visible.

What you'll see in the dom is `<!--ng-if="userIsLoggedIn"-->` And once the boolean flips to true, then the commented html line will turn into all of your actual html.

Comment: Super helpful.  Thanks!  These answers have helped clarify what I was going after.  For this particular case, I think `ng-if` is what I'm going after since I don't want anything showing up in the DOM.  Would the JS equivalent to `ng-if` just be a regular `if` statement?

Comment: @Farid because of the amount of DOM manipulation that ng-if causes, the JS equivalent would probably be fairly complex. Or at the very least contain a lot of jquery which could be difficult code to maintain in the future. Usually you want to find a 3rd party library to do heavy duty DOM manipulation instead of making your own in-house method. While an if statement could be used to watch a boolean to determine if things need to be done, like ng-if does. You'd have to write a lot more code than just a iif statement to do all of the DOM manipulation logic that would be necessary.

Comment: I was a little afraid that would be the case (which may be why Angular was/is so popular).  Right now, my goal is to do all client side logic using pure JS rather than use a framework (I'm not a fan of the "Flavor of the month" issue in the JS community).  And as a new dev, this should help my JS skills.  By the way, I really appreciate your explanations, and for not making me feel dumb for asking questions that may not make perfect sense, so thanks.

Comment: I think the last thing I would ask is if I wanted to view Angular's algorithm for their `ng-if` directive, is there an easy-ish way to do that (or even possible)?  I was thinking that looking at the js file at `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js` might help, but I don't know if it would.

Comment: I don't know if it is going to help you much, but here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js is the source code for the ng-if directive. I can understand wanting to take an all JS approach, but I would say this. Frameworks are 100% here to make our coding lives easier, and better. Frameworks make maintaining future code 1000x easier. For a learning experience, for sure, try and do it all with just JS. But in a production environment where code you write today could have to be changed months later by a different person, frameworks can be a necessity.

Comment: Also look up and heavily research the SOLID principles of programming. Read about it until you absolutely get it. Read it from multiple sources, do practice programs, whatever it takes to be sure you understand each letter in the acronym and how it relates to code you write. I can't stress it enough. When I got started it got me into a proper mindset that helped me have good programming habits right out the gate. It doesn't matter if your code can do complex, amazing things. If it isn't clean, maintainable, readable code, it isn't good code. These are tried and true methods worth knowing.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll be sure to read up on that.  And thanks for the github link!  I admit that while I keep hearing about the importance of writing good code, I felt like it wouldn't really matter for my personal projects (only when working on a team).  I'm starting to realize that may not be the case.  I think you're right that frameworks are supposed to make our lives easier, but it doesn't feel too stable to me.  For example, Angular 2 barely came out a few months ago, and now it's on Angular 4 (granted there were only minor changes, and there never really was an Angular 3).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to actually replicate ng-hide, then you would use jQuery.addClass method.

ngHide simply watches for the model value bound to it, and consequently adds/removes ng-hide class. This class simply adds a css rule 'display:none' rendering the element hidden.

However, using it for authentication based roles wouldn't usually be a good idea though. You would be simply making it invisible, but it will still be in the DOM and hence accessible.

Comment: Awesome.  That's basically what I'm getting at.  Using it for authentication purposes.  How would you go about doing it?  I figured it would have to be JS logic rather than a CSS `hide` or `show`.  I don't want info accessible from the DOM.

Comment: If this page contains some sensitive information then that information should not be coming out of the server in first place. Otherwise if not, it doesn't really matter even if you do a window.location redirect to prevent user from accessing that page(dependant on your application entierly). It all depends upon your stack, frameworks used etc. I think you've asked a wrong question. The answer to the question is what I've posted ( you might want to mark it accepted btw ). Search google or post a new, better phrased question if u dont find it. I bet there will be a lot of them around

Comment: Thanks, again, for the feedback.  This was actually my second attempt at asking this question.  I don't think I asked the wrong question.  My first attempt was a lot more detailed, but some people didn't like it.  I'm just trying to figure out how to keep unauthenticated users from viewing certain pages.  `ng-hide` just does a `display: none` in CSS, which isn't what I want.  `ng-if` sounds like the answer.  By the way, if the page contains sensitive information and you say it shouldn't come from the server, then where should it come from?